# How do I switch to Cycles render engine?

Tags: interface, blender-internal-render-engine

I just downloaded blender and it says at the top that I am in blender render. I want to make it on cycles render. How can change this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To switch render engines, click the drop down on the header of the *info menu* at the top of the screen where it currently says Blender Render. You will be presented with 3 options. Blender Render, Blender Game, and Cycles Render. Choose the desired option from there.

[image]

Comment: This menu is no longer there in Blender 2.9. I have no idea how to find it now.